# HP Pavilion g6 - 64 bit high temperature

Tags: 12.04, overheating, hp-pavilion

I have ubuntu 12.04 and my temperatures are constantly over 55°C

I've tried jupiter power saving mode without results.

I've tried installing ATI proprietary drivers but there wasn't a significant change; although there is a post-installation upgrade driver ubuntu is not able to install, due to some errors I can't understand.

I've not yet tried opening and cleaning the laptop, but I don't think this could be the problem, since on windows, on the same laptop, the temperatures are lower. (When on Ubuntu I can physically sense the heat coming a side of the pc).

What else should I tried?

Comment: no tips anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I afraid of facing the same issues.

Therefore have nt yet installed Ubuntu on HP Pavilion G6-2007 TX laptop.

It seems Ubuntu is not great while working with laptops like HP. As HP itself provides the drivers and utilities for Microsoft. They dont have support for Linus/Unix as such. Still you can visit HP Support.

I have mailed HP Support bt have nt yet recd any reply.

If any good news from HP do post it in here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I solved it by manually installing the driver from HP's website: `amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64` + jupiter with option power on demand. Temperatures are now 55-60.